# Strange screen resulutions between tablets on bootstrap3

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

At the moment i make a slicing job with bootstrap3. All is set up and works great, all is responsive and shows good on ipad, mobile phones.

I have a ipad3, and also i have a small tablet Prestigio with 7 inch screen. I look no Ipad, all is go right with `1020px`, but on small prestigio tablet i see there is a `1060px` wide `windows width`. Is the a browser error, tablet mistake?

If i set up for `md` classies bigger width, on desktop i can see diferences, but on small prestigio this rule dont take difference, becouse width is `1060px`

Comment: I think you didn't understand bootstrap documentation properly. Please have a look documentation or please provide sample code of your error

Comment: There is a browser error. I put a Opera mobile, and on Small tablet all working right.